# Java Regexp discussion2

Tags: java, regex

Having this Pattern for a regular expression :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\.](?s)executeRule\\(\\s*?(.+?),\\s*?('.+?'),\\s*(\\[.+?\\]\\s*\\);)");
```

I have a text like :

```
setSomething(false);
executeRule(document, 'PublishDocumentsToEmail', [
    'xmlMapping':'xmlmapping.TagRegLike',
    'emailAddress':'EMAIL(mymail@mail.com)',
    'emailSubject':'Test',
    'emailText':'test',
    'filenameSuffix':'test']
);

System.out.println("bla");

executeRule(document, 'PublishDocumentsToJMS', [
    'xmlMapping':'xmlmapping.TagRegLike',
    'emailAddress':'EMAIL(mymail@mail.com)',
    'emailSubject':'Test',
    'emailText':'test',
    'filenameSuffix':'test']
);
```

I want to find the sequences that contain the executeRule pattern. 
My regular expression successfully finds only the first pattern occurence; all the patterns that follow after this first pattern will contain the previous patterns.

E.g. the first time I parse I find

```
executeRule(document, 'PublishDocumentsToEmail', [
    'xmlMapping':'xmlmapping.TagRegLike',
    'emailAddress':'EMAIL(mymail@mail.com)',
    'emailSubject':'Test',
    'emailText':'test',
    'filenameSuffix':'test']
);
```

I do some replacements on the pattern so it becomes

```
executeRule(document, 'PublishDocumentsToEmail', [
        'xmlMapping':'xmlmapping.TagRegLike',
        'emailAddress':'EMAIL(mymail@mail.com)',
        'emailSubject':'Test',
        'emailText':'test',
        'filenameSuffix':'test']
         ,crs
    );
```

After this I recursively call the same parsing method with the new text which is

```
setSomething(false);
executeRule(document, 'PublishDocumentsToEmail', [
    'xmlMapping':'xmlmapping.TagRegLike',
    'emailAddress':'EMAIL(mymail@mail.com)',
    'emailSubject':'Test',
    'emailText':'test',
    'filenameSuffix':'test']
    ,crs
);

System.out.println("bla");

executeRule(document, 'PublishDocumentsToJMS', [
    'xmlMapping':'xmlmapping.TagRegLike',
    'emailAddress':'EMAIL(mymail@mail.com)',
    'emailSubject':'Test',
    'emailText':'test',
    'filenameSuffix':'test']
);
```

and my regexp will match the entire section from

```
executeRule(document, 'PublishDocumentsToEmail', [
    'xmlMapping':'xmlmapping.TagRegLike',
    'emailAddress':'EMAIL(mymail@mail.com)',
    'emailSubject':'Test',
    'emailText':'test',
    'filenameSuffix':'test']
    ,crs
);

System.out.println("bla");

executeRule(document, 'PublishDocumentsToJMS', [
    'xmlMapping':'xmlmapping.TagRegLike',
    'emailAddress':'EMAIL(mymail@mail.com)',
    'emailSubject':'Test',
    'emailText':'test',
    'filenameSuffix':'test']
);
```

How can I get it to match only my second pattern ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't thoroughly read your examples but you could either use `\G` in your pattern to start after the last match or just loop over the matches when using `Matcher#find()`.

Hope that helps.

*Update*:

> After this I recursively call the same parsing method with the new text which is  ...

Why would you call that recursively? I don't see any recursion so you might just iterate over the matches you found in the first call.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `find(index)` where the `index` is after the first / already modified occurrence.

[Matcher.find(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Is that all you're trying to do, add `,crs` as the last line of all `executeRule` strings with that same structure?  That's simple enough:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?m)^executeRule\\([^\\[]*\\[(\\s*)[^\\]]*\\]", "$0$1,crs");
```

I just matched everything up to the closing `]` (capturing a sample of some leading whitespace along the way), then plugged it back in and added the `,crs` line.  If your needs are more complicated than that, you'll need to tell us exactly what they are.  But I'm sure there will be a better solution than making multiple passes over the input like you're doing now.